# How to require license acceptance for NuGet package through .csproj file

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I'm moving away from `.nuspec` files for .NET Core/5/6 NuGet packages, but I cannot figure out how to set equivalent of the `<requireLicenseAcceptance>` element in the `.csproj` file.

I'm including a license file called `license.txt` in the package like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="license.txt">
        <Pack>True</Pack>
        <PackagePath></PackagePath>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

I then set the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageLicenseExpression></PackageLicenseExpression>
    <PackageLicenseFile>license.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This results in the following in the generated `.nuspec` file:

```
<license type="file">license.txt</license>
<licenseUrl>https://aka.ms/deprecateLicenseUrl</licenseUrl>
```

I'd like `<requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>` to also be included in the generated `.nuspec` file, to make the contents of `license.txt` to pop up when installing the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh. I didn't realize it could be set through the project properties, and doing so revealed what I *should* have guessed: the element name is nearly the same, just prefixed with "Package".

.nuspec:

`<RequireLicenseAcceptance>True</RequireLicenseAcceptance>`

.csproj:

`<PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>True</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>`